# Constant width in bokeh graph with datetime axis

Tags: python, bokeh

I set up a stacked bar graph in bokeh, each bar indicating one month:

[image]

The respective code bit looks as follows:

```py
p.vbar_stack(
        categories,
        x="zeit",
        width=2629800000 * 0.9,
        color=Category20c[len(categories)],
        source=plot_data,
    )
```

The width is specified in milliseconds, corresponding to the average length of a month. I multiply this by 0.9 to create a gap between bars. The problem is that due to actual differences in month lengths, the gaps between bars differ. This is most striking between February and March (e.g. the third and fourth bar from the left in the picture).

**How can I make bar widths (and gaps) robust to lenghts of months?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, semantically it's not really a datetime axis, it's a categorical axis. If you switch to a proper categorical axis, your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Well it's categories of datetime :). I used to have months as categories (formatted as strings, not as datetime). Then the bars look fine, but one has to specify x axis labelling manually. This is why I prefer to stick to datetime.

Comment: @E.Sommer You want for all months to have the same width. The datetime axis intrinsically assigns different width to different months. Even if you come up with some custom way to compute the gaps, your bars will end up having different widths.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to have variable width bars you can use a `timedelta` for the width. We have to create one for each month. This deals with the Feb/March issue. I've used `line_width` for the separation between the bars.

```
df['days'] = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: datetime.timedelta(days=x.days_in_month))

plot_data = ColumnDataSource(df)

p.vbar_stack(
    categories,
    x="zeit",
    width='days',
    line_width=1, 
    line_color='white',
    color=Category20c[len(categories)],
    source=plot_data,
)
```